# it is impossible to exchange a member, determining certificate of an object. Try to add a new object with a new certificate

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Hi guys! When i try to update my table with the help “linq to sql” i get an exception with an message which says like this

1. it is impossible to exchange a member, determining certificate of an object. Try to add a new object with a new certificate, and then delete the existing object.
2. Construction of my table in DB is [Field1(int, PK), Field2(varchar(15), PK), Field3(varchar(32), PK), Field4(int, PK)], there is no any constraint and trigger.
3. in MSSQL i can do any operation, for example, "update", "insert" and "delete", but in my application i can only insert and delete my records
4. My entity class, according on table from DB

```cs
[DataContract]
[Table(Name = "dbo.MyTable")]
public class MyTable: DataContext
{
    private int _Field1;

    private string _Field2;

    private string _Field3;

    private int _Field4;

    private EntityRef<MyTable1> _MyTable1;

    private EntityRef<MyTable2> _MyTable2;

    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanging()
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanging != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanging(this, emptyChangingEventArgs);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        this._MyTable1 = new EntityRef<MyTable1>();
        this._MyTable2 = new EntityRef<MyTable2>();
    }

    public MyTable()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    [Association(IsForeignKey = true, Name = "MyTable_MyTable1", OtherKey = "Field4", Storage = "_MyTable1", ThisKey = "Field4")]
    public MyTable1 MyTable1
    {
        get { return this._MyTable1.Entity; }
        set
        {
            MyTable1 entity = this._MyTable1.Entity;
            if (entity == value && this._MyTable1.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue)
                return;
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            if (entity != null)
            {
                this._MyTable1.Entity = (MyTable1)null;
            }
            this._MyTable1.Entity = value;
            if (value != null)
            {
                this.Field4 = value.Field4;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Field4 = 0;
            }

            this.SendPropertyChanged("MyTable1");
        }
    }

    [Association(IsForeignKey = true, Name = "MyTable_MyTable2", OtherKey = "Field1", Storage = "_MyTable2", ThisKey = "Field1")]
    public MyTable2 MyTable2
    {
        get
        {
            return this._MyTable2.Entity;
        }
        set
        {
            MyTable2 entity = this._MyTable2.Entity;
            if (entity == value && this._MyTable2.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue)
                return;
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            if (entity != null)
            {
                this._MyTable2.Entity = (MyTable2)null;
            }
            this._MyTable2.Entity = value;
            if (value != null)
            {
                this.Field1 = value.Field1;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Field1= 0;
            }

            this.SendPropertyChanged("MyTable2");
        }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "Int", Storage = "_Field1", IsPrimaryKey = true, CanBeNull = false)]
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public int Field1
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Field1;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Field1 != value))
            {
                this._Field1 = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "VARCHAR(15)", Storage = "_Field2", IsPrimaryKey = true, CanBeNull = false)]
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string Field2
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Field2;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Field2 != value))
            {
                this._Field2 = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "VARCHAR(32)", Storage = "_Field3", IsPrimaryKey = true, CanBeNull = false)]
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string Field3
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Field3;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Field3 != value))
            {
                this._Field3 = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "Int", Storage = "_Field4", IsPrimaryKey = true, CanBeNull = false)]
    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public int Field4
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Field4;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Field4 != value))
            {
                this._Field4 = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Considering there are no hits in Google for that particular exception message, could you post the **actual** exception message, and not a write-up of it? Also, which type of exception did you get?

Comment: If that is a translation of the actual exception, try to find the English version on http://unlocalize.com/. This will also help you searching the web for it.

Comment: I am from Russia and i get message of this exception in Russian language 

1. "Значение члена "Field2" объекта измененного типа "MyTable".
"Не удается изменить член, определяющий удостоверение объекта.
Попробуйте добавить новый объект с новым удостоверением, а затем удалить существующий объект." 
2. type of the exception is System.InvalidOperationException
3. if you give me some information about how i can get an exception in English, i will give you it

Comment: "Value of member 'Field2' of an object of type 'MyTable' changed.
A member defining the identity of the object cannot be changed.
Consider adding a new object with new identity and deleting the existing one instead."

Comment: Hmm, it appears to me that this problem is caused by what entity framework just cannot update fields with attribute "isPrimaryKey = true"...But why not? it's difficult for linq to sql?